# ASP.NET Core Middleware Breaks Physical File Controller Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

I use the following middleware to replace the response content:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    var body = context.Response.Body;

    using (var updatedBody = new MemoryStream()) {
        context.Response.Body = updatedBody;

        await next();

        context.Response.Body = body;

        updatedBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var newContent = new StreamReader(updatedBody).ReadToEnd();

        // Replace content here ...

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(newContent);
    }
});
```

This works fine. However now say I have the following action method:

```
public IActionResult Image() {
    return PhysicalFile(@"C:\myimage.jpg", "image/jpeg");
}
```

When it tries to display this image it won't load, but if I remove the middleware then it does.

Please note that I am using ASP.NET Core 3.

Comment: _"I use the following middleware to replace the response content"_ - but why do you do that? Why do you load every response in a StreamReader and update its contents? If you explain the X of your XY problem, we won't have to help you solve Y.

Comment: But if you really must do this, then check whether the content type is `text/html` and/or a whitelist of content types that you actually want to treat this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I have come up with:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    var body = context.Response.Body;

    using (var updatedBody = new MemoryStream()) {
        context.Response.Body = updatedBody;

        try {
            await next();
        } catch {
            throw;
        } finally {
            context.Response.Body = body;
        }

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 200 && context.Response.ContentType != null && context.Response.ContentType.Contains("text/html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            updatedBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(updatedBody)) {
                var newContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                // Replace content here

                await context.Response.WriteAsync(newContent);
            }
        } else {
            if (updatedBody.Length > 0)
                await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(updatedBody.ToArray());
        }
    }
});
```

[This article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Jun/03/Building-Live-Reload-Middleware-for-ASPNET-Core) helped thanks to @CodeCaster's suggestion. As an added bonus I have fixed an issue where it breaks the developer exception page by wrapping a try/catch around the call to the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
    app.UseWhen(context => context.Response.ContentType == "text/html", subApp => subApp.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var body = context.Response.Body;

        using (var updatedBody = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = updatedBody;

            await next();

            context.Response.Body = body;

            updatedBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var newContent = new StreamReader(updatedBody).ReadToEnd();

            // Replace content here ...

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(newContent);
        }
    }));
```

Comment: I originally updated this with @CodeCaster's suggestion but it looks like this won't work as the ContentType is null and therefore my middleware doesn't run. My problem with the initial answer was that I would have to add to the condition for every action that I return a physical file.